# Custom EditText in Android drops words from swype/KitKat keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, textwatcher

I have created a custom MyEditText - inherited from EditText. I want to modify the text being displayed, so I created a TextWatcher, and called addTextChangedListener() to bind it to my MyTextEdit - in the Constructor.

It intercepts the input alright, except when dealing with swype keyboards. I have no problem dealing with pasting, nor deleting of text (1 or more characters), just with swype input. The problems I see in my TextWatcher are:

1. first swype word is entered OK, but without a leading space. The second swyped word is NOT entered at all, instead a space is added to the text. The 3rd appears, the 4th only space, and so on.
2. in some swype keyboards (for instance on Galaxy 5) SPACE key is totally ignored.
3. these problems also appear in modern Android versions that have swype capabilities built-in.

Any clues?

If it helps, I also keep getting "TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled." when trying to select text (long press). My widget is Focusable, is Clickable (also in touch mode), and I also implemented onCheckIsTextEditor() that returns true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I created my own Editable, and set it as the new text, instead of manipulating the Editable I got from afterTextChanged(Editable newText).

In addition I am now calling TextView.beginBatchEdit() and TextView.endBatchEdit() before, and after my changes, respectively.

Last thing to notice is that if you use spans be careful not to touch spans that do not belong to you. For instance, iterating over all spans (inherited from spanned) and removing them is a very bad idea ;-)

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and unable to fix it. Can you add some basic code to your answer too ?